# TryInto<GenericArray> without panicking

Tags: rust, error-handling

I am using the [`chacha20poly1305`](https://docs.rs/chacha20poly1305/latest/chacha20poly1305/) crate, which uses a [`GenericArray` v0.14.7](https://docs.rs/generic-array/0.14.7/generic_array/) for its [`Key`](https://docs.rs/chacha20poly1305/latest/chacha20poly1305/type.Key.html).
I now need to convert that key from a `Vec<u8>`. However [`GenericArray::from::<&[u8]>()`](https://docs.rs/generic-array/0.14.7/src/generic_array/lib.rs.html#564) is implemented to panic upon conversion errors (and thus also will `try_from()`). I would, however, like to convert from `Vec<u8>` to `Key` without panicking and handling errors gracefully.

Is there a way to do this without going the long way and converting into `[u8; SIZE]` fist? If not, is it possible to get the key's size from `Key` somehow without using a magic number in my code?

My current attempt is:

```rust
use clap::Parser;
use clap_stdin::FileOrStdin;
use ios_log_decrypt::EncryptedLog;
use log::error;
use rpassword::prompt_password;
use std::io::{stdout, Write};
use std::process::exit;

const KEY_SIZE: usize = 32;

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
struct Args {
    #[arg(index = 1, help = "path to the encrypted log file")]
    logfile: FileOrStdin,
    #[arg(long, short, help = "hexadecimal decryption key")]
    key: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    env_logger::init();

    let args = Args::parse();
    let encrypted_log = EncryptedLog::new(args.logfile.to_string());
    let key: [u8; KEY_SIZE] = hex::decode(args.key.unwrap_or_else(|| {
        prompt_password("Decryption key: ").unwrap_or_else(|error| {
            error!("{error}");
            exit(1)
        })
    }))
    .unwrap_or_else(|error| {
        error!("{error}");
        exit(2);
    })
    .try_into()
    .unwrap_or_else(|vec: Vec<u8>| {
        error!("Invalid key size: {}", vec.len());
        exit(3);
    });

    for block in encrypted_log.decrypt(&key.into()) {
        match block {
            Ok(ref bytes) => stdout().write_all(bytes).expect("could not write bytes"),
            Err(error) => error!("{error}"),
        }
    }
}
```

Which is pretty ugly, since I need to hard-code the key size of `32` in my code and thus it is not directly tied to the size of `Key`.
While the size of `Key` is unlikely to change in the future, possible discrepancies between `Key`'s size and `KEY_SIZE` will lead the program to panic again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a conversion function:

```rust
use generic_array::{ArrayLength, GenericArray};

fn generic_array_try_from_slice<T, N>(data: &[T]) -> Option<&GenericArray<T, N>>
where
    N: ArrayLength<T>,
{
    if data.len() == N::to_usize() {
        Some(data.into())
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```